# c# - How to disable path exist check in OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

follwing simple code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog _fileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            _fileDialog.Title = CarPlus.Base.Properties.Resources.ContentSettingsDatabase_FileOpen_TitleRestore;
            _fileDialog.CheckPathExists = false;
            _fileDialog.CheckFileExists = false;
            _fileDialog.ValidateNames = false;
            _fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
            _fileDialog.InitialDirectory = _searchPath == null ? System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer.ToString() : _searchPath;
            _fileDialog.Filter = "Wiederherstellungsarchiv (*.fbk)|*.fbk";

            // Display OpenFileDialog
            if (_fileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                return (_fileDialog.FileName);

            return (null);
```

the sense is to give the user the possibility to select a file or to write down his own path and file name. that is necessary, because the selected file is a database backup file for a firebird instance. the firebird server will use this file to restore the database but he mus have access to that file and of course, if the firebird instance is running on another computer the file path can be different.
my problem is, if i write down in the dialog 'c:\bar.fbk' is everything fine even when the file not exist on the local computer, but if i write 'c:\foo\bar.fbk' i will get an error message that the path not exist.
but why? my filedialog setup includes

```
_fileDialog.CheckPathExists = false;
```

who knows why?

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you using `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` and not `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`?

Comment: @TsahiAsher, I guess because of WPF. [Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) is in PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: @ToshiBoy: isn't that the point of the question - OP says he has done that & shows it in the code - but still gets the error message.

Comment: Have you considered to simply use a `SaveFileDialog` instead?

Comment: @bassfader: Possibly because that does exactly the same.

Comment: Can you not just handle the exception and take the file name anyway?

Comment: before i used the System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialo, but ... the same behaviour ( ; the SaveFileDialog has the same problem ; exception? when i write down my path 'c:\foo\bar.fbk' i get no exception i get an error message window :/; really is that a bug or is that a misunderstanding of the function of that option?